# Clion can't load external libraries

Tags: std, clion

After cloning a repo from github, my Clion can't load std libs, and I can't use them.

[image: wrong status]

It should be like this:

[image: right status]

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi EvanHong. To make question easier to read, please instead of URLs use images embedded in question. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, greenmaker, tks for your advise, but i'm sorry about that. Stack Overflow has set rules that only having 10 points can i embed images into my questions. Thank you again.

Comment: Which package manager (for example Conan...) is needed for your project? Do you have automatically generated file CMakeLists.txt in the root directory of the project ?

Comment: Yes, I've generated CMakeLists.txt, but it didn't work. I finally solved this problem by moving .idea to the root directory (perhaps it will cause some problems, but i haven't seen that yet).